# cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 3 (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having this error when going through an image with OpenCV and NumPy.
Here's my code:

```py
import math
import cv2
import numpy as np

palletes = [[255,85,85],[80,250,123],[255,184,108],[40,42,54],[68,71,90],[248,248,242],[98,114,164]]
def fcp(pixel, palletes): #Prototype for now
    ans = math.inf #Just a filler
    pal = [0,0,0] # Yet another filler
    for pallete in palletes:
        #Pythagorean Theorem (but it's 3D)
        result = math.sqrt(sum(list(map(lambda x,y: (x-y)**2, pixel, pallete))))
        if result < ans: ans = result; pal = pallete
    return pal, ans

# read the wallpaper.png image with opencv
img = cv2.imread('wallpaper.png')
# convert the image to rgb lists for every pixel
img_rgb = img.reshape((img.shape[0]*img.shape[1],3))
for p, pixel in enumerate(img_rgb):
    img_rgb[p] = fcp(list(pixel), palletes)
# undo the reshape
img_rgb = img_rgb.reshape(img.shape[0],img.shape[1],3)
# save the image to wallpaper_new.png
cv2.imwrite('wallpaper_new.png', img_rgb)
```

I get the error when trying to perform the `img_rgb[p] = fcp(list(pixel),palletes)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, the answer was quite simple - the fcp function returns two values, even though only the first one was expected. Python needs tracebacks.

Comment: Python does provide tracebacks, but you error was at the top level, your code with `img_rgb[p] = ...`.  It's in the indexed assignment.  `img_rgb` is (n,3) shape, so `img_rgb[p]` is a (3,) slot.  A (2,) array can't be put in a (3,) as the error says.